# A tricky and maybe impossible Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

I am working with the 2-dimensional form of the Coulomb potential $V_c=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and in my calculation I eventually will need to compute the following Fourier Transform integrals:

\begin{equation}
I_1 = \int e^{-i q y} \left(\frac{d}{dx} V_c\right) dy
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
I_2 = \int e^{-i q y} \left(\frac{d}{dy} V_c\right) dy
\end{equation}

I believe I can do the first one and its equal to $I_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \left| q\right|  K_1\left(q \sqrt{x^2} \text{sgn}(q)\right)$ but am completely stumped on the second one. I cant seem to find it in any integral tables nor any remotely useful tricks I can use. Might anyone offer some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can maybe use the differentiation becomes multiplication by frequency in Fourier domain. That is often used in attacking linear differential equations with Fourier Transforms.

Comment: The remaining expression $\int e^{-iqy} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dy$ if I'm not recalling wrong a hyperbolic substitution could help since "hyperbolic one" those functions satisfy $f(x)^2 + g(x)^2 = 1$ so you get rid of square root.

Comment: Hhmm interseting. Trying this now.

Comment: The second integrant differs by a fractor of $\frac{x}{y}$. You could use integration by parts here.

Comment: I have tried the integration by parts idea, but it doesn't seem to work because the boundary term doesn't vanish at $\pm \infty$. I am still looking into differentiation idea.

Comment: Mathematica gives $I_1 = -2 \operatorname{sign}(x) |q| K_1(|xq|)$ and $I_2 = 2q K_0(|xq|)$. I am trying to figuring out a solution, but not quite successful so far as I'm not a guru of special functions.